# Asterisk 1.8 Simple PHP GUI

Tags: php, api, sip, voip, asterisk

I would like to use PHP to manage multiple asterisk boxes. The actions I need PHP to are very basic.

- Add/Edit SIP Trunks
- Add/Edit Incoming Routes
- Add/Edit Extensions
- Have all asterisks servers use the DB for call logs

I don't know the best way for PHP to interact with Asterisk. Also I don't know how to get them to use the same DB for the CDRS. I think editing `/etc/asterisk/cdr_mysql.conf` on all the asterisks servers will work for the the CDRs.

Comment: not really sure if this should be tagged mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You can check freepbx.org project(yes,it use php) to see how it can be done. Or you can try use asterisk realtime architecture - all configs stored in db and asterisk read it from db. To do asterisk reload you need use AMI.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API